# How to put a caption on top of Latex table

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I want to put a caption on top of the following table in Latex.

```latex
\begin{center}

\begin{tabular}{ | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | p{5cm} |}
\hline
GT & MT & PT & ML & FP & FN & ID & FM & Rc & Pr \\ \hline
abc & abc & abc & abc & abc & abc & abc & abc & abc & abc \\ \hline

\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{center}
```

Comment: Please use [tex.se] for pure LaTeX questions.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You do not make a table, but only a tabular (which cannot have a caption). You have to make a table first, and then a tabular:

```
\begin{table}[htb]

    \centering % instead of \begin{center}
    \caption{Here you can type in your caption}
    \vspace{10mm} % Adjust the height of the space between caption and tabular

    \begin{tabular}{ | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | p{5cm} |}
        \hline
        GT & MT & PT & ML & FP & FN & ID & FM & Rc & Pr \\ \hline
        abc & abc & abc & abc & abc & abc & abc & abc & abc & abc \\ \hline
         \hline
    \end{tabular}

\end{table}
```

[Further explanation](https://www.latex-tutorial.com/tutorials/beginners/latex-tables/): "The table environment merely holds our other environments and allows to add a caption to our table. The actual data is contained in the tabular environment and we center the table on the page using the center environment."

Comment: Thank you very much it worked. How to put an empty space between caption and table? I am trying \hline but it is showing an error.

Comment: Space between the caption and tabular can be created with `vspace`. See my updated answer :)

Comment: `\hline` is for in the tabular, not in the table (difficult but important difference).

Comment: Upvoted _also_ for `\centering % instead of \begin{center}`, that I've written on SO some dozen times ;) Also `[h]` alone should be avoided: better `[htb]`.

Comment: @MattAllegro, you're right! Edited the placement option.